# Active Record Third-Tier Relation Query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have models User, Filter and Messages:

- User  `has_many :filters` and `has_many :messages, as: :owner`
- Filter `belongs_to :user`, `has_many :messages, as: :processor`
- Messages `belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true` and `:processor, polymorphic: true`

What is the right way to query `"Filter.find_by(user_id: [@whatever].id).messages"`without returning `undefined method "messages" for nil:NilClass`?

Comment: you are getting `undefined method "messags" for nil:NilClass` because there is no filter in your database with the given user_id. Find an existing user_id from database and pass it in the find_by

Comment: I have an instance variable in `users#show` that uses this query. What's the best way to avoid raising `undefined method "messages" for nil:NilClass` error for first-time users that don't have any filters created?

Comment: @Dimitry_N try this :  Filter.find_by(user_id: [@whatever].id).try(:messages)

Comment: @SachinPrasad Yes, Sir! Like a charm! Did not know about `.try`. Thank you so much!

Comment: @SachinPrasad do you want to add your comment as answer so I can mark it resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
 Filter.find_by(user_id: [@whatever].id).try(:messages)
```